# Comparing array to var during iteration(cont.)

Tags: javascript

So here's my problem.. Might just be tired but, I want counter to ++ only if number has not occurred in array.

Meaning during the 4 iterations, counter should ++ only on iteration 1,3,4

```
var array = [], number, temp = [4,2,5,9], counter = 0;
for(var i = 0; i <= 3; i += 1) {
    array.push(i);
    number = temp[i];
}
document.write(counter);
```

But I'm drawing a blank here... Help?

(No this isn't homework)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (array.indexOf(number) < 0)
    counter++;
```

Answer (score 0):

<strike>unfortunately JS doesn't have an "in_array", but it's pretty straight forward:</strike>
@MikeSamuel pointed out you can use indexOf (thanks Mike). So with that being said:

```
var array = [], number, temp = [4,2,5,9], counter = 0;
for(var i = 0; i <= 3; i += 1) {
    array.push(i);
    number = temp[i];
    if (temp.indexOf(i)==-1) // much simpler, assuming you're checking if i is in temp.
      counter++; // increase counter if it is not.
}
document.write(counter);
```

I'm not sure *where* you want the logic, so you'll have to figure that out or be more specific. Just know that you need to iterate through the array you're checking and check if the "needle" is in the "haystack" array.

**EDIT** Had the opposite, just added bool to check for existence.

Comment: `Array.prototype.indexOf` is defined in ES5.  Don't you need to `break` on a match if you're testing containment so that you don't over count when `temp` contains duplicates?

Comment: @MikeSamuel: I wasn't aware indexOf had a prototype for arrays. Good to know. And I changed the loop (though I'll be changing it again now that I know indexOf will work). Thank you.

Comment: just a note that jQuery provides and in_array function... http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/